# Render different Code for Each Request | Random | Split Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I'm searching for a solution for a simple Split Testing (without statistics).

Basically for each request I want a different image to be rendered.

```
<div class="hero-panel">
  <img src="test1.png" alt="img" />
  <!-- or -->
  <img src="test2.png" alt="img" />
  <!-- or -->
  <img src="test3.png" alt="img" />
</div>
```

Per request, one of the 3 images. Has anyone a good solution for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can select a random image between these three by

```
 <img src= "<%=['test1.png', 'test2.png', 'test3.png'].sample%>" alt="img" />
```

Comment: Even easier would be `<img src='test<%= %w(1 2 3).sample %>.png' alt='img' />`